# / in asked user input variable name - sql plus - oracle

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to do this:

```
     select * from tab where date= to_date('&date_dd/mm/yyyy','dd/mm/yyyy');
```

but  it asks `'date_dd'` and not `'date_dd/mm/yyyy'`.

How can I escape `/` character? I think that the problem is here!

Comment: This is not a valid SQL statement... are you trying to select all dates from your table where it is the same as the user input? What user input are you expecting?

Comment: i just want that, when i ask a variable from input, the name specified of variable must contain a / character... isn't possible??

Comment: Why does the _name_ of the variable have to contain a `/`?  Are you able to answer my questions? What data are you trying to select from your table and what are you expecting the user to input?

Comment: for example... select 'name','cod', '&DATA_dd/mm/yyyy' from tab; i want to ask the name and suggest to user who use this query, that he must insert date in dd/mm/yyyy format...

Comment: Probably it is easier to prompt something like: "Please enter the date (dd/mm/yyyy):"

Answer (score 1):

You can't have this "/" in a variable's name, so it won't appear to the prompt as you do it. Use Lajos solution:

```
PROMPT Please enter the date with format dd/mm/yyyy:
select * from tab where date= to_date('&date','dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Will ask it so:

```
SQL> @my_script
Please enter the date with format dd/mm/yyyy:
Enter value for date:
```

You could also use `ACCEPT` e.g. following inspirations from e.g. [Oracle SQL*Plus ACCEPT Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868770/oracle-sqlplus-accept-statements)
:

```
accept date PROMPT 'Please enter the date with format dd/mm/yyyy:'
select * from tab where date= to_date('&date','dd/mm/yyyy');
```